# Why mockReturnValueOnce seems not to work?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest along Meteor, but I'm getting the following problem while trying to implement tests using `Collection.find().fetch()`.

I'm mocking the function `find` and `fetch`, as you can see below. However, the value return by `fetch` is always the first one.

Shouldn't the value be different every time, since I'm using `mockReturnValueOnce`?

```
import { describe, test } from "@jest/globals";
import { Users } from "../../../collections"; // a Mongo collection

describe("#Users test suite", () => {
  const mock1 = {
    userId: "111aaa",
    email: "user1@test.com",
  };

  const mock2 = {
    userId: "222bbb",
    email: "user1@test.com",
  };

  const mock3 = {
    userId: "333ccc",
    email: "user1@test.com",
  };

  test("Fetch test", () => {
    Users.find.mockImplementation(() => ({
      fetch: jest
        .fn()
        .mockReturnValueOnce(mock1)
        .mockReturnValueOnce(mock2)
        .mockReturnValueOnce(mock3),
    }));

    // getting same result in every fetch call
    console.log(Users.find().fetch()); // { userId: '111aaa', email: 'user1@test.com' }
    console.log(Users.find().fetch()); // { userId: '111aaa', email: 'user1@test.com' }
    console.log(Users.find().fetch()); // { userId: '111aaa', email: 'user1@test.com' }
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `Users.find.mockImplementation`?

Comment: Hi, how you doing? `Users` is my mongodb collection -> `new Mongo.Collection('users')`. `find` is a mongodb method to select documents in a collection. `mockImplementation` is a Jest function to mock the implementation of a function, making it to do and return what you want (https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn)

Comment: how does that function get into `Users.find`?

Comment: It not really get into `Users.find`, I'm using [stubs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-jest-stubs) to use `meteor/meteor` imports with Jest, since it can't handle it self on Meteor packages. So, using this stubs, I can get into `Users.find` and use Jest functions.

Comment: @MarcusM. did you find solution? Can you share? 